# Solution of the transient heat equation for an infinite domain with a circular hole and angular symmetry

Tags: heat-equation, symmetry, cylindrical-coordinates

I mean to solve the heat equation in 2D
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac 1r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)    \tag{1}
$$

in an infinite domain with a circular hole
$D = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 \ge b^2 \}$.
The boundary conditions (BC) are fixed
$$T(b,t) = T_1   \tag{2a},$$
$$T(r,t) = T_0 \quad \text{as} \quad r \rightarrow \infty   \tag{2b},$$
for all $t$.
The initial condition (IC) is
$$T(r,0) = T_0   \tag{3}$$
for all $b \le r$.

**This is what I did** (I am posting all details in case it helps).

First I changed variables $U = (T − T_0) / (T_1 − T_0)$.
So
$$
\frac 1r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial U}{\partial r}\right) = \frac 1\alpha \frac{\partial U}{\partial t}    \tag{4},
$$
$$U(b,t) = 1   \tag{5a},$$
$$U(r,t) = 0 \quad \text{as} \quad r \rightarrow \infty   \tag{5b},$$
$$U(r,0) = 0   \tag{6}.$$

Then I used the Laplace transform $\bar{U} = {\cal L}[U]$, obtaining (the IC gets embedded in the Laplace-transformed ODE)
$$
\frac{d^2 \bar{U}}{d r^2} + \frac 1r \frac{d \bar{U}}{d r} = \frac 1\alpha \left( s \bar{U} - U(r,0) \right)   \tag{7},
$$
$$\bar{U}(b,s) = 1/s   \tag{8a},$$
$$\bar{U}(r,s) = 0 \quad \text{as} \quad r \rightarrow \infty   \tag{8b}$$

Using the IC (6) I get
$$
r^2 \frac{d^2 \bar{U}}{d r^2} + r \frac{d \bar{U}}{d r} - \frac {r^2 s}{\alpha} \bar{U} = 0   \tag{9}.
$$

The solution is
$$
\bar{U}(r,s) = A \, I_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, r \right) + B \, K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, r \right)   \tag{10}.
$$

Using (8b), $A=0$.
Using (8a),
$$
B = \frac{1}{s K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, b \right)}   \tag{11}.
$$

Then
$$
\bar{U}(r,s) = \frac{1}{s} \frac{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, r \right)}{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, b \right)}   \tag{12}.
$$

**This is where I am stuck**.
The last step is an inverse transform.
The two hurdles I find are:

1. How to get rid of $\sqrt{s}$.
2. How to deal with $K_0$ in the denominator.
   For $K_0$ in the numerator, I guess I could use ${\cal L}^{-1}[K_0(\sqrt{s} r)] = e^{-r^2/4t} / 2t$ [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845034/inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-modified-bessel-function)], or a series expansion, once I handle the above.

**I found two related cases**, with solutions, which contain similar difficulties as 1 and 2 above. None of them explains how to proceed:

1. https://people.bath.ac.uk/masrs/ma20010/chap5.pdf , Eqns. (5.50), (5.51) (using the present symbols):
   $$
   \bar{U}(r,s) = \frac{A}{s} \frac{\sinh \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, r \right)}{\sinh \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, b \right)}   \tag{5.50}.
   $$
   $$
   U(r,t) = A \left( \frac rb + \frac 2\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sin \left( n\pi \frac rb \right) e^{-n^2 \pi^2 \alpha t / b^2} \right)   \tag{5.51}.
   $$
2. https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=56882e7a614325f8078b457c&assetKey=AS%3A313540840230912%401451765369569 , Sec. 7.1.2
   $$
   \bar{U}(r,s) = \frac{A}{s} - \frac{Ab}{rs} \frac{\sinh \left(\sqrt{s \alpha} \, r \right)}{\sinh \left(\sqrt{s \alpha} \, b \right)}  .
   $$
   $$
   U(r,t) = A - \frac{Ab}{r} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \text{erfc} \left( \frac{b (2n+1) - r}{2 \sqrt{\alpha t}} \right) - \text{erfc} \left( \frac{b (2n+1) + r}{2 \sqrt{\alpha t}} \right) \right]  .
   $$

Can someone comment: (1) how to invert Eqn. (12), (2) is there is an alternative general solution method?

**Related:**

1. [Heat equation in cylindrical coordinates with Neumann boundary condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210475/heat-equation-in-cylindrical-coordinates-with-neumann-boundary-condition)
2. [Laplace transform of heat conduction PDE in cylindrical coordinates.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104563/laplace-transform-of-heat-conduction-pde-in-cylindrical-coordinates)
3. [Inverse Laplace Transform of the modified Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845034/inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-modified-bessel-function) [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845034/inverse-laplace-transform-of-the-modified-bessel-function)]
4. [Inverse Laplace of $\frac{\sinh{x\sqrt{s}}}{s^2\sinh{\sqrt{s}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965257/inverse-laplace-of-frac-sinhx-sqrtss2-sinh-sqrts)
5. https://planetmath.org/usinglaplacetransformtosolveheatequation

Comment: Start by working with $T := T_0 + u$.

Comment: @Aruralreader - I already transformed into $T^{*} = (T-T_0)/(T_1-T_0)$. That shortens writing, but it doesn't help with the points where each of the methods I tried fail. 
Would you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Consider a Laplace transform with respect to $t$. This'll allow you to introduce the initial condition and produce an ODE you can solve.

Comment: @K.Jiang - That boundary condition is not needed, and probably redundant, leading to a possibly indeterminate system. The fact that there is a hole does not preclude heat flux. There are actually many physical systems with such condition. Moreover, the problem within a finite domain and the same condition ar $r=b$ is readily solved.

Comment: @Jean-LucBoulnois: Spot on, and the required decay as $r\to\infty$ will remove one of them. +1

Comment: @Aruralreader - Please check heavily updated OP. I appreciate you suggesting general lines to follow.
Would you mind letting me know if you actually know how to get to the **final solution**, from the point I am at?
I would also be grateful if you could post more details on that, if not the solution procedure itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution of the present problem via the Laplace transform method as suggested in the OP is shown in [Inverse Laplace transform of $ \bar{U}(r,s) = \frac{1}{s} \frac{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, r \right)}{K_0 \left(\sqrt{s/\alpha} \, b \right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4850783/inverse-laplace-transform-of-barur-s-frac1s-frack-0-left-sqrt)

There might be other methods for inverting the Laplace transform along the lines of the examples quoted (series expansion), or also methods other than Laplace transform.